# Ubuntu Crash no reponse

Tags: 16.04, freeze, crash, syslog

I have my ubuntu 16.04 installed on a dual core mother board. 
However, the system seems not really stable. This really annoy me a lot. 
This time I look into the system.log can any one help me on that ?
I am not sure where to start the debugging.

[syslog1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qd8m.png)

[syslog2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sca8H.png)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by ( the system seems not really stable)?

Comment: I mean not really stable, means for example, it may freeze at random time. And I have looked into the syslog every time when it was no response, however, no clue on that. That's why I decide to upgrade the kernel from 4.8 to 4.10. Just want to know any suggestion on debug this problem. I also thought may be the system was sleep or hibernate, but I am not sure to verify this....